# How to add a div to a radio button?

Tags: cakephp, radio-button, cakephp-2.0, form-helpers

I'm a new user of CakePHP.
I'm trying to add some div to contain my input + my label.

This is what I've got :

```
<?php 
$option =  array ("value1" => "labelContent1", "value2" => "abelContent2");
echo $this->Form->input('name', array('type' => 'radio', 'options' =>  $option, 'div' => true, "legend" => false));
?>

<div class="input radio">
    <input type="hidden" name="data[Quiz][name]" id="ModelName_" value=""/>
    <input type="radio" name="data[Quiz][name]" id="ModelName1" value="value1" />
    <label for="ModelName1">labelContent1</label>

    <input type="radio" name="data[Quiz][name]" id="ModelName2" value="value2" />
    <label for="ModelName2">labelContent2</label>
</div>
```

And this what I would like to have :

```
<div class="input radio">
    <input type="hidden" name="data[Quiz][name]" id="ModelName_" value=""/>
    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="data[Quiz][name]" id="ModelName1" value="value1" />
        <label for="ModelName1">labelContent1</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="data[Quiz][name]" id="ModelName2" value="value2" />
        <label for="ModelName2">labelContent2</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Do you know if it is possible to make it by using the FormHelper ?

Answer (score 6):

I know it's an old thread but I had to reply. 
The correct way to achieve this without creating a bad mark-up is to use before and after options:

```
echo $this->Form->input('name', array( 'type' => 'radio',
                                     'separator'=> '</div><div>',
                                     'before' => '<div>',
                                     'after' => '</div>',
                                     'options' =>  $option,
                                     'label' => true,
                                     "legend" => false
                                   )
                                );
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can't achieve that with the Form Helper. The radio options are not wrapped in anything. See [code](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/View/Helper/FormHelper.php#L1388).

You can add `'separator' => '<br/>'` to the Form->input options, to display each option in its own line.

or implement it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

```
you can try this

$option =  array ("value1" => "labelContent1", "value2" => "abelContent2");

    echo $this->Form->input('name', array( 'type' => 'radio',
                                        'separator'=> '</div><div>',
                                         'options' =>  $option,
                                          'label' => true,
                                          "legend" => false
                                         )
                                    );
```

Comment: Doesn't this result in a mal-formed markup due to the first and last `div` not being opened/closed?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$option =  array ("value1" => "labelContent1", "value2" => "abelContent2");
echo $this->Form->input('name', array(
    'type' => 'radio',
    'options' =>  $option, 
    'templates' => ['radioWrapper' => '<div>{{label}}</div>'], 
    "legend" => false));
?>
```

This seems to work well for Cake 3.+